# Evaluate format template content in (Semantic-)Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am using semantic mediawiki to store and describe information about scientific papers. In this context I would like to build a citation template that links to the page where the paper is described.

Every Paper has an identifier which is a combination of first author and year with the property like this: `[[Has citekey:someauthor2019]]`. I use a  template to cite this paper as `{{Cite | someauthor2019}}` and combine the Cite template with a format template to render it as a link to the page with the name of the citekey.

The problem is that when I do it with the templates below, it will actually *display* the wikitext:

```
[[Name of the page | someauthor2019 ]]
```

instead of evaluating it to appear as the named link:

```
someauthor2019
```

This is the semantic-mediawiki ask query to get the paper information:

- Template:Cite

```
{{#ask: [[Has citekey::{{{1}}}]]
 |?Has citekey
 |format=template
 |template=Cite Text
}}
```

This is the format template to deal with the results of the query:

- Template:Cite_Text

```
[[{{{1}}} | {{{2}}}]]
```

How can I get the avaluated result of a named link to be displayed instead of the wikitext?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
 |link=none
```

this will pass {{{1}}} result as raw text to your template

You request becomes :

```
{{#ask: [[Has citekey::{{{1}}}]]
 |?Has citekey
 |format=template
 |template=Cite Text
 |link=none
}}
```

Source :

https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries#Standard_parameters_for_inline_queries